# Search for an exact phrase with a comma in Google: "hello, john"

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I know that Google lets you search for an (almost) exact phrase by putting the phrase in quotes:

```
"hello, john"
```

This will find both instances of `hello john` and `hello, john`.

I want to find only results that have the comma. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least with Google.

There are more accurate search engines. I'd recomend http://symbolhound.com/
Not a great company, not a great design but fits better for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite possible because search engines (Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo) ignore comma individuality. One way would be to run search on search page via **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>F</kbd>** like:

[image: 0]